# Mysql split string on punctuation

Tags: mysql, regex, string

I have a database where office users have created a "poo man's categorization" by prefixing the administrative title field with a category. For instance, you have records like

```
Applications - When to Apply
Applications- Fees
Admission: GPA requirements
Admissions: Bursar
```

We are adding a category column, and I want to get (as close as possible) all the unique user-created categories in the title field. From the examples above, `Applications`, `Admission`, and `Admissions` are good enough.

How can I write a query to return the first part of a field, split on the first non-alphahnumeric character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this isn't possible with any of the built-in MySQL functions. There's no function for searching a string for a character outside a set, e.g. the first non-alphanumeric character.

You can write a stored function that does it, by looping over the string and calling `SUBSTR()`. But you're probably better off searching the net for a user-defined function that can split a string using a regular expression.

Comment: MariaDB 10.0.5 REGEXP_REPLACE(), REGEXP_INSTR() and REGEXP_SUBSTR()

Comment: @RickJames Nice to know, but the question is about MySQL, not MariaDB.